# Как выполнить команду os.system("python script.py") из скрипта, собранного в PyInstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qprocess

Я собрал пакет в *PyInstaller*. У меня есть `.exe` файл, созданный из скрипта **main.py**.

В этом скрипте мне нужно выполнить команду `os.system("python script.py")`.

Как я могу это сделать, если в пакете, собранном *PyInstaller* присутствуют только `.dll` библиотеки Python?

Comment: Вообще там и сам интерпретатор должен быть

Comment: Да как бы нету.

Comment: Да как нет если собранный Pyinstaller-ом EXE-ник запускается на на системе где никогда не устанавливался Python?

Comment: Там нет интерпретатора как такового!  То есть, никакого python.exe нет и впомине. Там есть pyWin32 с кучей dll. Я не знаю, как это запускается вообще.

Answer (score 1):

По предыдущему вопросу я понял, что у вас с `PyQt5` все в порядке.

Есть: `system_AV_QProcess.py`

Выполнняем: `pyinstaller -c -F system_AV_QProcess.py`

Запускаем: `system_AV_QProcess.exe`

`os.system` не самый подходящий вариант, т.к. блокирует GUI, 
но если вы используете `QProcess`, он выполняет аналогичную задачу, 
и вам не нужен поток.

**system-AV-QProcess-222N.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    signalOnFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start task", clicked=self.on_clicked)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)
        self._process = QtCore.QProcess(self)
        self._process.finished.connect(self.on_finished)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            "Select File", 
            "", 
            "Python Files (*.py)")

        self._process.start('python', [f"{fileName}"])              # <---

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        self.signalOnFinished.emit()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self._process.kill()
        super(MainWindow, self).closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да с первым вопросом тяжело... Как вы уже знаете, я пишу приложение на системе `Mac OS` для `Windows`. На Mac-у установлен `Wine`. В Wine я установил `PyQt5` и `PyInstaller`. Но беда в том, что у Mac-а проблемы с работой библиотек `libEGL.dll` и `libGLESv2.dll` и иже с ними, которые использует PyQt5. В виртуалке та же беда. То есть, корректно тестировать на Mac-е PyQt5 под Windows невозможно.  С текущим вопросом я поступил проще: просто сделал из второго скрипта `exe` и запускаю его через `win32api` из первого скрипта